# Adding an editable field to omniauth generated / existing user

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, omniauth

I'm using omniauth-twitter to create and authenticate users in my rails app and I'm successfully getting everything I need from Twitter, avatar, username, description, etc. But I'd like to let users add a custom string to display on their account page.

I added a column to the User table and ran the migration. The column is there.

I can't seem to get the update form to work, however. I'm not seeing errors. I just get a page refresh. Since I didn't have an existing form or controller methods to begin with I added them manually.

Here's my Users controller (I'm using friendly-id, hope that doesn't throw you.)

```
 class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @users = User.all
  end

  def show
    @user = User.friendly.find(params[:id])if params[:id]
  end

  def edit
    @user = User.friendly.find(params[:id])if params[:id]
  end

  def update
    @user = User.friendly.find(params[:id])if params[:id]
  end

  private

  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:custom_text)
  end
end
```

I'm not sure if I need both edit and update methods here, but I thought I'd try.

Here's my form (SLIM Template) which I include on the user's show page:

```
= form_for @user do |f|
  = f.text_field :custom_text
  = f.submit
```

The submit button works, as it were, but nothing is updated.

I'm pretty sure I'm just overlooking something painfully obvious.

Comment: Could you add the definition of the routes for this controller to your question and also a snippet from your development.log of when you view & submit the form?

Comment: I dont seem to find `html: { :multipart : true }` in your form

Comment: A edited the question to be more clear. While my ultimate goal is to have a file field, the main issue I'm having is not related to the file field itself. I'm unable to even get the contents of the text field to update the database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
I can't seem to get the update form to work, however. I'm not seeing errors.
```

Nothing is getting updated because you are *not updating* anything in the first place. As per the current code in the `update` action, its just selecting the record to be updated from the database but doing nothing with it.

```
  def update
    @user = User.friendly.find(params[:id])if params[:id] ## Simply selecting
  end
```

**In order to update the fetched record**, you should call either **`update or update_attributes`** method on the instance of `User` model *passing the changed attributes values to the method*.

### SOLUTION:

Use the following updated code in your `UsersController`. I have also *DRYed* up the code little bit by adding a `before_action` callback named `set_user`. The `set_user` method will be called every time before performing the actions such as `show`, `edit` and `update` and will take care of setting the instance variable `@user`.

```
 class UsersController < ApplicationController
  ## Adding a before action callback
   before_action :set_user, only: [:show, :edit, :update]

   def index
     @users = User.all
   end

   def show
   end

   def edit
   end

   def update
     if @user.update(user_params)
       ## Redirect to user show page on successful update
       redirect_to @user, notice: 'User was successfully updated.'
     else
       ## Render user edit page again upon failure to update
       render action: 'edit'
     end
   end

   private

   def set_user
     @user = User.friendly.find(params[:id]) if params[:id]
   end

   def user_params
     params.require(:user).permit(:custom_text)
   end
 end
```

Comment: I knew it was something very fundamental along these lines. Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing your form code to set the `multipart:true` to allow file to be sent

Try this and then upload the photo

```
= form_for @user,html: {multipart: true} do |f|
  = f.file_field :custom_photo
  = f.submit
```

Comment: Also you might want look at [this](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4.2)

Comment: I'm not worried about the file field right now. I commented that line out. I can't even get a text string to save.

Comment: @DennisBest Show us your form code HTML evaluated code

Answer (score 0):

I might also be missing something painfully obvious or new in Rails 4, but it seems like you should actually be telling the DB to update your record:

```
def update
  @user = User.friendly.find(params[:id]) if params[:id]
  @user.update_attributes(user_params) if @user
end

private

def user_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:custom_text)
end
```

Without this second line in the `update` action, it's just finding the record and not doing anything with it...